# How add more items into collation menu in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, collation, pgadmin-4

I want to create a new database in pgAdmin (PostgreSQL 16 on Widnows 10) but i can only chose from 3 items for database Collation.

If i list available collations by

```
select *
from pg_collation pgc
```

, there is 2245 records.

[Collation menu in pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8xR8.png)

I was looking for solution but it seams that nobody else had this problem.
Is there any possiblity to edit items in Collation combobox?

Thank you.
PS

**[Update]**
I created a new database using a query widnow. I chose "cs_CZ.UTF-8" for COLLATE and CTYPE. The database was created but there are no values for collation and character type in the definition tab [image: Database with blank collation and character type] .

Is this normal?
I should maybe read some basic informacions about the PostgreSQL database because for now i am a litle bit dissapointed. I used the Firebird database for my previous projects and there wasn't such obstacles.

Maybe Postgre 16 is too "young" and it will better to use the version 15? Or the pgAdmin is not the best tool and i should try the DBeaver?
What do you think?

Comment: Or just create the database using the psql console.

Comment: That looks buggy. Use a different client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older version of PGAdmin from before PostgreSQL 15, so it doesn't expose all [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-LC-COLLATE) parameters that would let you select a valid set of parameters required to use those other collations. You probably need to override [`locale_provider`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-LOCALE-PROVIDER)

> `locale_provider`
> Specifies the provider to use for the default collation in this database. Possible values are `icu` (if the server was built with ICU support) or `libc`. By default, the provider is the same as that of the [*`template`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-TEMPLATE). See [Section 24.1.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/locale.html#LOCALE-PROVIDERS) for details.

and [`icu_locale`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-ICU-LOCALE):

> `icu_locale`
> Specifies the ICU locale (see [Section 24.2.2.3.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING-CREATE-ICU)) for the database default collation order and character classification, overriding the setting [*`locale`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-LOCALE). The [locale provider](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-LOCALE-PROVIDER) must be ICU. The default is the setting of [*`locale`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-LOCALE) if specified; otherwise the same setting as the template database.

As a workaround, you can connect to any database on this cluster, open a regular SQL window and run the command:

```sql
create database collation_test2 
   template template0
   encoding 'UTF8'
   locale_provider icu 
   icu_locale 'cs-CZ-x-icu';
```

Or update to [PGAdmin 7.7 or above](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/database_dialog.html), where those parameters are exposed through the database dialog.

Comment: I downloaded the latest installer for PostgreSQL 16.1 (Windows x86-64) from official pages. My pgAdmin version is 7.6.

Comment: @PavelSala Did you make sure you're not connecting to an older version? It's entirely possible to have multiple versions of either PGAdmin or PostgreSQL installed, and even running at the same time. What do you get when you run `select version();`?

Comment: I installed the PostgreSQL 16.1 with this ( https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1258792 ) installator on the clean Windows 10. So no other versions could be there. `select version();` -> `PostgreSQL 16.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1935, 64-bit`

Comment: @PavelSala Hold on, I overlooked you posted your pgAdmin version is 7.6. I've addressed that in the answer: you need 7.7 or above. The EDB installer from the link you gave either bundles or lets you add pgAdmin 4 v.7.8 through stackbuilder it offers. If you do get pgAdmin from the EDB package, you should be able to find a pgAdmin 4 entry under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PostgreSQL 16` path. I've tested that just now and I'm seeing all the new options in that database dialog.

Comment: I reinstaled PostgreSQL 16 through stackbuilder like you sugested and now i have pgAdmin 4 v 7.8. Database dialog now offers "Local Provider" item. After set this to "icu" i am able to select "ICU Locale" which i want. Thank you for your help!